# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{k}x\sqrt{(1+ae^{-bx})} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the integral
$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{k}x\,\sqrt{\,1 + a\,\mathrm{e}^{-bx}\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x}$ where $a$, $b$ and $k$ are positive constants. Any suggestion ?.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this integral appear in some specific context?

Comment: If $a\in(-1,1)$, expand $\sqrt{1+z}$ as a Taylor series, replace $z$ with $ae^{-bx}$ and integrate termwise.

Comment: $a$ is actually 2, $k$ is around 1 and $b$ is 0.5 in my particular case. Context? Not really, I'm going back and forth in my research and just came up with the need to calculate this integral (it may not even be correct how I got to it, but I couldn't believe it looked so easy but I couldn't find how to evaluate it). The term inside the square root is from a force that is only important for small displacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer on 'how to compute it' but too long for a comment. For $a=2$, Mathematica provides an antiderivative: $\int dx\ x\sqrt{1+2e^{-bx}}=$
$$
\frac{2 \sqrt{2 e^{-b x}+1} \left(e^{\frac{b x}{2}} \text{Li}_2\left(e^{-2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)-b x \sqrt{e^{b x}+2}-2 \sqrt{e^{b x}+2}+b x e^{\frac{b x}{2}} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{e^{b x}+2}+e^{\frac{b x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-e^{\frac{b x}{2}} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2-2 e^{\frac{b x}{2}} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \left(\log \left(1-e^{-2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)-1\right)\right)}{b^2 \sqrt{e^{b x}+2}}+C\ ,$$ in terms of arcsinh and polylog. I have checked by differentiating it, and it seems it's correct. Mathematica gives the general antiderivative for any $a$, but I am not yet able to reobtain the integrand by differentiating it.

Comment: Thanks! Maple was not giving me any solution but if Mathematica does, that's good enough :)

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[2]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}\left(\,{#2}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{a,b,k > 0\,,\quad a \equiv \expo{\mu}\,,\ \mu \in \mathbb{R}}$.

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{k}x\root{1 + a\expo{-bx}}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{bk}x\root{1 + a\expo{-x}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{bk}x\root{1 + \expo{-\pars{x - \mu}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over b^{2}}\int_{-\mu}^{bk - \mu}\pars{x + \mu}\root{1 + \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

With the sub$\ds{\ldots\root{1 + \expo{-x}} = t}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{k}x\root{1 + a\expo{-bx}}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over b^{2}}\int_{c}^{d}\bracks{-\ln\pars{t^{2} - 1} + \mu}t\,
\pars{-\,{2t \over t^{2} - 1}}\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
{2 \over b^{2}}\int_{c}^{d}\bracks{\ln\pars{t^{2} - 1} - \mu}\,
{t^{2} \over t^{2} - 1}\dd x\tag{1}
\\[3mm] &\ \mbox{where}\ c = \root{1 + \expo{-\mu}} = \root{1 + {1 \over a}}\
\mbox{and}\ d = \root{1 + \expo{bk - \mu}} = \root{1 + {\expo{bk} \over a}}
\end{align}

---

The only 'non-trivial' integrals in $\pars{1}$ are given by:
\begin{align}
\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t^{2} - 1} \over t^{2} - 1}\,\dd t\quad\mbox{which is reduced to the integrals}\quad
\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t \pm 1} \over t \pm 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}

---

1. \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t - 1} \over t - 1}\,\dd t} & =
   \color{#f00}{\left.\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{t - 1}\right\vert_{\ c}^{\ d}}
   \end{align}

   ---
2. \begin{align}
   &\color{#f00}{\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t - 1} \over t + 1}\,\dd t} =
   \int_{c - 1}^{d - 1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 2 + t}\,\dd t =
   -\int_{c - 1}^{d - 1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t/\pars{-2}}\,{\dd t \over -2} =
   -\int_{\pars{1 - c}/2}^{\pars{1 - d}/2}{\ln\pars{-2t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
   \\[3mm] = &\
   \left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}\ln\pars{1 - t}\ln\pars{-2t}
   \right\vert_{\ \pars{1 - c}/2}^{\ \pars{1 - d}/2} +
   \int_{\pars{1 - c}/2}^{\pars{1 - d}/2}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
   \\[3mm] = &\
   \color{#f00}{\ln\pars{1 + d \over 2}\ln\pars{d - 1} -
   \ln\pars{1 + c \over 2}\ln\pars{c - 1} -
   \Li{2}{1 - d \over 2} + \Li{2}{1 - c \over 2}}
   \end{align}

   ---
3. $\ds{\color{#f00}{\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t + 1} \over t - 1}\,\dd t}}$ is similar to the case $2.$

   ---
4. $\ds{\color{#f00}{\int_{c}^{d}{\ln\pars{t + 1} \over t + 1}\,\dd t}}$ is similar to the case $1.$

   ---

Answer (score 0):

With **Mathematica 13.3.0** general solution:

$\int_0^k x \sqrt{1+a \exp (-b x)} \, dx=\\\frac{2 \left(2 \sqrt{1+a}-e^{-\frac{1}{2} (b k)} \sqrt{a+e^{b k}} (2+b k)+\text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)
   \left(-2+\text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)+2 \log \left(\frac{2 \left(-1+\sqrt{1+a}\right)}{a}\right)\right)-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b k}{2}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \left(-2+\sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b k}{2}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+2 \log \left(1-e^{-2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b k}{2}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}\right)\right)+b k \log \left(\frac{e^{\frac{b
   k}{2}}+\sqrt{a+e^{b k}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-2 \text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{b
   k}{2}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}\right)\right)}{b^2}$

Code:

`1/b^2 2 (2 Sqrt[1 + a] - E^(-((b k)/2)) Sqrt[a + E^(b k)] (2 + b k) +  ArcCsch[Sqrt[ a]] (-2 + ArcCsch[Sqrt[a]] + 2 Log[(2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + a]))/a]) -  ArcSinh[E^((b k)/2)/Sqrt[ a]] (-2 + ArcSinh[E^((b k)/2)/Sqrt[a]] +  2 Log[1 - E^(-2 ArcSinh[E^((b k)/2)/Sqrt[a]])]) +  b k Log[(E^((b k)/2) + Sqrt[a + E^(b k)])/Sqrt[a]] -  PolyLog[2, E^(-2 ArcCsch[Sqrt[a]])] +  PolyLog[2, E^(-2 ArcSinh[E^((b k)/2)/Sqrt[a]])])`